# UK IHS surcharge incorrect question

Tags: uk-visa

I'm applying UK ICT partner dependent visa for my spouse. I'm the main applicant and I'm still outside UK. We are planning to travel together. In IHS page, it is asking us to enter my visa expiry date. Since I havent traveled yet to UK, I dont have visa. It is not mentioned in spouse application that main applicant is already in UK. How to solve this problem? This issue is similar to [Tier 4 dependant visa - IHS form asking for incorrect information](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/21076/tier-4-dependant-visa-ihs-form-asking-for-incorrect-information)
I dont see answer for above post also. So asking again.
Thanks in advance

Comment: For 100% clarity, are you both applying at the same time, or is your own application as the main applicant already submitted and pending a decision and you are now submitting a subsequent application for your dependent?

Comment: yes, we are applying at the same time. Main application payment done and Biometric appointment not yet taken.

Comment: I am facing the same issue right now. If you have resolved that issue, please let me know. Would be much appreciated!